# Hurdle model with weighted count variable as dependent variable?

Tags: poisson-distribution, zero-inflation

My question concerns the feasibility of applying a hurdle model when my dependent variable is not exactly a count, but a "weighted count".

More precisely, my weighted count variable (Weighted_Intrusions) is the product of the following:

Weighted_Intrusions = Number of Intrusions (count variable) * Associated Distress (Continuous, on a scale from 0-100).

I'm having some trouble to figure out:

a) Is my outcome variable Weighted_Intrusions still considered a count variable, or shall I rather consider it continuous? I have the feeling that Weighted_Intrusions does not refer to a count anymore, but is continuous now. However I am not sure about this...

b) My dependent variable Weighted_Intrusions still contains many zeros and displays overdispersion. One interesting model to use would be a hurdle model, but is this possible with my variable?

If you have any ideas on this matter, I would be glad to hear them!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. The units look like "total distress" to me rather than a count.
2. The GLM family you pick specifies a mean-variance relationship. You can use any mean-variance relationship you like.  You even deliberately misspecify it and still have consistent and calibrated estimates by plugging in a robust covariance matrix estimate.

Comment: This could be considered quasi/pseudo maximum likelihood. You might also consider a two-part model (a continuous analog of the hurdle).

Comment: Thank you for your responses.@AndrewM; thank you for your hint. Assuming that my new Variable "Weighted_Intrusions" resembles the original count variable in terms of its mean-variance relationship, am I right to assume that I should be able to specify for instance the poisson or negative binomial distribution? (even though, from textbooks, we learn that these distributions are for counts?). It then seems that whether or not I have a count doesn´t matter, what matters in reality is the mean-variance relationship (but usually this relationship would fit a poisson or bn distribution in counts) ?

Comment: Thank you @DimitriyV.Masterov . With two-part model, do you mean executing two different analyses (which would be "one" in the hurdle model)?

Comment: In the two-part model, a binary choice model is fit for the probability of observing a positive-versus-zero outcome. Then, conditional on a positive outcome, an appropriate regression model is fit for the positive outcome. Then you can combine them together for the purpose of predicting outcomes or marginal effects.